# Publishing Azure Function App - Error: Value Cannot be null. Parameter name

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, publish, azure-function-app

I am trying to publish my azure function app to the cloud. I get the to the point where I am able to click finish after selecting my subscription and picking which Function app.

Once I press "Finish" I get this error:

"Value Cannot be null. Parameter name: s"

Not sure what this means. But after checking here I seen that it may have something to do with AzureWebStorageJobs. So I got the connection string from my storage account and added it to my local settings but that still did not work.

Am I missing a step here?

My Steps:

1. Created ServiceBusTrigger (entered in sub, Connection string, and topic and didnt change anything else)
2. Then right clicked on the project and went to publish.
3. Selected my subscription and added my function app.
4. Hit Finish and then got the error in the image.

Error here:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add screenshot of an error?
Are you publishing from VS?

Comment: @AndriyBilous  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hWa1.png Sorry about that. Here is the link. I added my steps to it as well.

Comment: I'm having the same problem now. Did you ever find a solutions?

Comment: Nvm i fixed it by creating a `local.settings.json` file and doing the correct config settings there. No idea why local config is needed for deploying to the cloud but it got rid of the error for me.

Comment: @Martijn what is the `local.settings.json` file content did worked for you?

Comment: @SandunPerera This was a while ago but if I remember correctly I had a `settings.json` file and I duplicated that and named the copy `local.settings.json`

Comment: @Martijn thanks for the reply, but my coleague found the issues that new .Net6 azure function expects the data to be submitted in camel case strictly than before in json serialisation options.